# How to get environment values using quasar-dotnev

Tags: vue.js, quasar

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
API_URL=localhost:8080
```

quasar.config.js

```
const env = require('quasar-dotenv')
 build: {
      env: env,
    ......
}
```

in Router, I am printing process.env but I am not getting values from .env file

Comment: Did you tried `process.env.NODE_ENV` ?

Comment: @talkhabi Yes, its undefined

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using the quasar framework with Vuejs.

So i added an ext :-

1. quasar ext add @quasar/dotenv : This will add extension for quasar dot env.
2. enter the details asked in CMD like name of file and filename for dev and prod.
3. After setting all these :-
   I simply copy pasted all the required variables in .development.env like :-
   API_URL = https..
4. After that I can access it using process.env.API_URL.

Link for reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR_2vbTlF78

If someone is working with other framework they can take reference from here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGPX-rSGIps